# Conditional clustering of elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a long list like:

```
list={{"2014 03 12 08 59 34", 0.3849}, {"2014 03 12 08 59 36", 0.38492}, 
      {"2014 03 12 08 59 38", 0.38495}, {"2014 03 12 09 16 20", 1.38522}, 
      {"2014 03 12 09 16 22", 1.38523}, {"2014 03 12 09 16 24", 1.38524},
      {"2014 03 12 09 16 26", 1.38524}, {"2014 03 12 09 16 28", 1.38524},
      {"2014 03 12 09 16 30", 1.38525}, {"2014 03 12 09 16 32", 1.38525}, 
      {"2014 03 12 09 16 34", 1.38525}, {"2014 03 12 10 10 01", 1.38529}, 
      {"2014 03 12 10 10 03", 1.38528}, {"2014 03 12 10 10 05", 1.38531},
      {"2014 03 12 10 10 07", 1.38532}, {"2014 03 12 10 10 09", 1.38534},
      {"2014 03 12 10 10 11", 1.38537}}
```

The first column is dates and the second some values. The list is sorted by date. I want to gather the elements in a way that every two consecutive elements have time difference less than *4 seconds*. The solution should be like:

```
{{{"2014 03 12 08 59 34", 0.3849}, {"2014 03 12 08 59 36", 0.38492}, 
  {"2014 03 12 08 59 38", 0.38495}}, {{"2014 03 12 09 16 20", 1.38522}, 
  {"2014 03 12 09 16 22", 1.38523}, {"2014 03 12 09 16 24", 1.38524},
  {"2014 03 12 09 16 26", 1.38524}, {"2014 03 12 09 16 28", 1.38524},
  {"2014 03 12 09 16 30", 1.38525}, {"2014 03 12 09 16 32", 1.38525}, 
  {"2014 03 12 09 16 34", 1.38525}}, {{"2014 03 12 10 10 01", 1.38529}, 
  {"2014 03 12 10 10 03", 1.38528}, {"2014 03 12 10 10 05", 1.38531},
  {"2014 03 12 10 10 07", 1.38532}, {"2014 03 12 10 10 09", 1.38534},
  {"2014 03 12 10 10 11", 1.38537}}}
```

What I have done is I defined

```
date@da_ :=  DateList[{da, {"Year", " ", "Month", " ", "Day", " ", "Hour", " ", 
                            "Minute", " ", "Second"}}]
```

Then

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, {a_, b_}, ___, {c_,     d_}, ___} :> {{a, b}, {c, d}} /;
            Abs@DateDifference[date@a, date@c, "Second"][[1]] < 4]
```

However this does not match the preferred output.

So how may I cluster my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This converts the special time format to seconds:

```
toSeconds = 
 AbsoluteTime[{#, {"Year", " ", "Month", " ", "Day", " ", "Hour", " ", "Minute", " ", "Second"}}] &
```

Then we use [`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Split.html), taking advantage of the fact that the list is already sorted:

```
Split[list, toSeconds@First[#2] - toSeconds@First[#1] < 4 &]
```